# Can i use @Transactional(readOnly = true) on a method that calls a stored procedure which returns resultsets but also updates rows?

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I have a method that calls a stored procedure via an `entityManager` instance

```
    ProcedureCall storedProcedureCall = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).createStoredProcedureCall(StoredProcedures.GET_WEB_APPLICATION_STATE_DATA_AND_UPDATE_USER_STATUS.toString());
```

This stored procedure retrieves the users preferences and also updates the users status from offline to online at the same time. Could i use `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` instead of `@Transactional` since the update query isn't done by the data requesting application itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be no. When i use `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` on a method that calls a stored procedure which both gets data and writes data i'll get the exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed
```